# How to disable automatic switch where active another switch in nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

In my project, which I find [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=j1ZTcl), I use the switch.  I use the switch. I want to do when checking out1, it should automatically make out2 disable. If I want to activate out2 I need to uncheck out 1, switched to return to active status, then I activate out2 and disable out1.

And out3 and out4 I want to function like out1 and out2.

Any idea please?

Comment: May I know what seems to be the challenge here, it should be all about binding the checked value of switch to isEnabled property of another switch?

Comment: I want to disable automatic out2 when I check out1, or disable out1 when I check out2.

Comment: Still not sure what is the issue, it should be as simple as binding the `isEnabled` property to the other switch's checked state.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `isEnabled` property of Switch to the `checked` state of other switch. Since you are using `FormGroup`, try this

```
<Label style="text-align: right" class="m-15"
     text='Out1' textWrap="true" row="0" col="0"></Label>
 <Switch formControlName="out1" style="text-align: left"
     class="m-15" [isEnabled]="!ConfigurationForm.controls['out2'].value"
     row="0" col="1"></Switch>
 <Label style="text-align: right" class="m-15"
     text='Out2' textWrap="true" row="0" col="2"></Label>
 <Switch formControlName="out2" style="text-align: left"
     class="m-15" row="0" col="3" [isEnabled]="!ConfigurationForm.controls['out1'].value"></Switch>
```